# Adaptive replacement cache (ARC) and add/update/remove

Tags: algorithm, caching

I read the [Adaptive replacement cache paper](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/event/fast03/tech/full_papers/megiddo/megiddo.pdf) and implemented it. I am thinking of using it as a general purpose cache in front of a database. Therefore sometimes I need to remove an item from the cache because it no longer is in that database. Additionally updates of an item need to be applied to the object in the cache. Lastly - when a new item is added to the database it may be sensible to add it in the cache as well. The problem is that the paper only describes **getting** items from it. I couldn't find how to implement those operations. Here is my reasoning based on my very recent experience with the algorithm:

- **Add** - this may be performed in a similar manner as **Get** when there is a cache miss but we use the item we already have instead of looking it up in the backend
- **Update** - the same as **Add** with the note that we replace the cached item if it is already present
- **Remove** - this is where I struggle to find a reasonable thing to do other than remove it from the T1/B1/T2/B2 if it is there

Could you help me figure out what to do in the context of the algorithm regarding the 3 operations?

Comment: That sounds correct. It would be similar with most any algorithm, like LRU, so it goes unsaid. Note that there are patent concern wrt ARC, but more importantly its hit rates are good but not stellar compared to other policies.

Comment: Thanks a lot @BenManes. I would accept the answer BTW. Despite the patent I still wanted to implement it since it is: easy, online and requires no prior knowledge about the access pattern. Could you mention the names of the other policies so I can take a look? I did a research and nothing took my fancy but I can reconsider.

Comment: [Caffeine](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine) uses W-TinyLfu. The next version will be adaptive by using hill climbing to walk the hit rate curve, which is more effective than ARC’s. In an adaptive [stress test](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/pull/263#issuecomment-462479921) it is nearly optimal while others are half the hit rate or worse. The simulator is really helpful for exploring ideas and figuring out what works.